# PHP OScommerce trying to select mysql db getting parameter error

Tags: php, mysqli, oscommerce

New to php, using http://www.oscommerce.com and trying to connect to mysql db- I am getting the following error

> Warning: mysqli_select_db() expects exactly 2 parameters, 1 given in C:\xampp\htdocs\public_html\walton\includes\functions\database.php on
>   line 24

Php Code - database.php

```
<?php
/*
  $Id$

  osCommerce, Open Source E-Commerce Solutions
  http://www.oscommerce.com

  Copyright (c) 2007 osCommerce

  Released under the GNU General Public License
*/

  function tep_db_connect($server = DB_SERVER, $username = DB_SERVER_USERNAME, $password = DB_SERVER_PASSWORD, $database = DB_DATABASE, $link = 'db_link') {
    global $$link;


    if (USE_PCONNECT == 'true') {
      $$link = mysqli_pconnect($server, $username, $password);
    } else {
      $$link = mysqli_connect($server, $username, $password);
    }

 Line 24:   if ($$link) mysqli_select_db($database);

    return $$link;
  }
```

Can someone advise?

Answer (score 1):

Final issue here was incompatible PHP and Oscommerce version. mysqli_select_db() expects 2 parameters link(mysqli link) and database name(string).   Also mysqli_pconnect() is deprecated use mysqli_connect().

```
Line 24: if ($$link)  mysqli_select_db($link,$database);
```

Comment: I tried this and i get the following now:

Warning: mysqli_select_db() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, string given in C:\xampp\htdocs\public_html\walton\includes\functions\database.php on line 23

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function msqli_select_db() in C:\xampp\htdocs\public_html\walton\includes\functions\database.php:23 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\public_html\walton\includes\application_top.php(70): tep_db_connect() #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\public_html\walton\index.php(13): require('C:\\xampp\\htdocs...') #2 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\public_html\walton\includes\functions\database.php on line 23

Comment: your link must be $link = mysqli_connect($server, $username, $password, $database);  and is only receiving a string ''db_link" because you have $link='db_link'

Comment: Do I need to remove the $link='db_link' from function 'tep_db_connect' and add this line in $link = mysqli_connect($server, $username, $password, $database); ?

Comment: No you already have it in the variable  $$link = mysqli_connect($server, $username, $password);   So on line 24 you can try.... if ($$link)  mysqli_select_db($$link,$database);  Also you may have a problem with mysqli_pconnect because it is deprecated.

Comment: That seems to have sorted that but also got a similar error: 

Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, string given in C:\xampp\htdocs\public_html\walton\includes\functions\database.php on line 45

$result = mysqli_query($query, $$link) or tep_db_error($query, mysqli_errno(), mysqli_error());

Comment: $result=mysqli_query($$link,$query)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190955/discussion-between-ra19-and-luis-cadena).